# No super method getLifecycle() after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, androidx

I have been trying to migrate my app to use androidx but I seem to encounter a strange error. From my activity which extends AppCompatActivity when I call `getLifeCycle()` it throws the following exception

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method getLifecycle()Landroidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle; in class Landroidx/core/app/ComponentActivity; or its super classes 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getLifecycle(FragmentActivity.java:324)
```

I believe that AppCompatActivity should be implementing LifecycleOwner but its not. Am I doing something wrong?
Here's my gradle dependencies

```
implementation files("libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar")
implementation "com.github.philjay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2"
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2"
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"

annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0" // use kapt for Kotlin

implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation "com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0"
implementation "com.github.franmontiel:FullScreenDialog:1.0.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
```

Comment: Did you enable Jetifier? Some of your dependencies might still be using the support library, which could cause conflicts.

Comment: @TheWanderer yes I did

Comment: Try implementing `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0`.

Comment: It looks like there's a `ComponentActivity` both at `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` and `androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity`. The former implements the LifecycleOwner interface, while the second doesn't. I think your IDE is using the first one and the runtime is trying to use the second one. I guess this is why AndroidX is still mostly in alpha.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks that was it! I removed the `androidx.core` dependency and it worked, will look more into the androidx packages and test that I don't need it elsewhere

Answer (score 14):

You should change the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` version to `1.1.0-alpha04`

Answer (score 12):

Just tried it in verision `1.1.0-alpha01` of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` and it is now working.

The `LifecycleOwner` interface is now implemented by `ComponentActivity` which is extended by `FragmentActivity` -> `AppCompatActivity`. You should now be able to get the `lifecycle` object from your activities.

Answer (score 7):

Reverting back to version 1.0.1 works for me.

```
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.1"
```

Comment: alpha version of 1.1.0 has the issue

Comment: [find your version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions) , click one you can find alpha versions

Answer (score 1):

In my case my problem was with the version 1.0.0-alpha05 of androidx activity, I revert to `1.0.0-alpha03` and it works fine